# Package mdframed with tikz rendering lines poorly

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, mdframed, rendering

I'm using TeX Live 2014 on Windows 8.1, and I'm having some trouble setting up a visually appealing definition environment. I'm trying to use the `mdframed` package with `tikz`, and I'm using an example that is almost verbatim from the `mdframed` documentation. It produces ugly and incomplete lines (no matter how far I zoom in on the pdf), which is particularly unfortunate because my document is aimed to be viewed on screens. Here is some minimal working code which produces the result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
\newcounter{counter}

\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{
\refstepcounter{counter}
    \ifstrempty{#1}
    {\mdfsetup{
        frametitle={
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!130]
        {\strut \textcolor{white}{Definition~\thecounter}};}}
}
{\mdfsetup{
    frametitle={
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!130]
        {\strut \textcolor{white}{Definition~\thecounter:~#1}};}}
}
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=gray!130,
        linewidth=1pt,topline=true,
        frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
\vspace{10pt}\begin{mdframed}[]\relax
}{\end{mdframed}\vspace{10pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
\blindtext
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

And here is an image of the output it produces:

[image]

I'm fairly confident that this has nothing to do with my pdf viewer, as I've tried to open the file using several viewers on several computers. What can I do to make the borders a consistent, stable width?

Comment: I have no problem here using an updated TeXlive 2014 on Linux.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436), and thanks for the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  Try opening it in Acrobat and look at several zoom levels if you still have the issue. It renders fine for me with TeXShop using TeXLive2014 on Mac.

Comment: I suggest you to update the packages.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. All of my packages are up to date, and I have opened the file in Acrobat at several zoom levels (I think I already said that). I've also tried viewing it in Google Drive viewer and on multiple different devices. I should probably also have mentioned that I have also tried this on MikTeX and had the same issue.

Comment: What is your version of `mdframed` package? Mine is 1.9b. See the log file to find yours.

Comment: Mine is mdframed 2013/07/01 1.9b as well. Should I upload the generated pdf so you can see the issue in more detail?

Comment: @fattybake, ok, lets open your pdf on Linux to see what happens. Send it.

Comment: It can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7D5XMJkN1uOS3Fic0gyN25nR2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @fattybake, sorry. The pdf is ok here. The same as mine. Try to update also tikz.

Comment: That's very strange. I'm pretty sure that package is up to date as well, but I'll double check. I guess I'll just wait and see if anyone else has had a similar problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns an issue which could not be reproduced. The OP is unregistered and has not been here since February so the chances of getting to the bottom of the mystery at this point seem slim, to say the least.